# Не работает нейросеть на python keras

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

По гайду написал следующий код:

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

dataset = loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')

X = dataset[:,0:2]
y = dataset[:,2]
print(X)
print(y)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)

model.predict(X)
```

CSV файл:

```
207,35,70.55
131,127,110.39
242,115.6,74.63
152,256,101.71
297,20,90.28
```

При обучении вижу такую картину:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 453ms/step - loss: 117123.0625 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: 209229606702546944.0000 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: inf - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: inf - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Пробовал менять функции активации, оптимизатор, добавлял скрытые слои. Параметр loss менялся, но всё равно точность была 0. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нарисовать графики зависимости x-y, то похоже у вас там просто нет никакого сигнала в данных.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(x=X[:,0],y=y)
sns.scatterplot(x=X[:,1],y=y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единственное что можно сделать - взять правильную метрику для регрессии и более традиционный  оптимизатор, чтобы всё это не улетело в космос и тогда хотя бы процесс не будет совсем уж расходиться в бесконечность. Плюс таки немного побольше нейронов. Но нормальное решение это всё-равно не даст, повторюсь - в ваших данных просто нет сигнала, сэмплы противоречат друг другу.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)

pred = model.predict(X)
print(pred)
print(pred.flatten()-y)
```

На выходе:

```
Epoch 1/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 325ms/step - loss: 2362.1326 - mse: 2362.1326
Epoch 2/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 1997.6973 - mse: 1997.6973
...
Epoch 99/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 448.9284 - mse: 448.9284
Epoch 100/100
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 448.9018 - mse: 448.9018
[[ 66.2372 ]
 [ 70.66355]
 [ 97.78726]
 [111.62021]
 [ 86.65694]]
[ -4.31280212 -39.72644867  23.15726196   9.91020874  -3.62306335]
```

Какие-то результаты получить удалось, но с довольно большой погрешностью.